# UITextfield selection of all text at becomeFirstResponder

Tags: text, uitextfield, selection

I need to highlighted all text in uitextfield when it become first responder. and user press any key the textfield will become blank and user can enter new text.

```
[m_titleTextField selectAll:self];
[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible =YES;
```

This code is not working...

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this problem,

use the same one but put into right place.

```
[m_titleTextField selectAll:self];
[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible =YES;
```

use in `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` delegate method of `UITextfield`...

Comment: It works, but if you have two text fields and start tapping around them, the menu stops showing. It's shown only once. Also selection works through time.